# How to Download UBUNTU 12.04 LTS on windows xp for writting on a CD?

Tags: 12.04

Since I can't start my Internet on Ubuntu 8.04 LTS on laptop, I first want to download it on a CD on windows XP. How can I download it on a CD and than re-install on Laptop? I will format my laptop which has Ubuntu 8.04 LTS. Which poses lot of problems.

Parag Shah

Comment: Why are you installing such an old version? Just download the recommended one from http://ubuntu.com/download.

Comment: ObsessiveSSOℲ > some people do not want to upgrade their OS every year. Installing LTS makes it possible to use a PC or a long time with out reinstalling as you already know.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I guess you should download the `Ubuntu 12.04` iso, burn it to a CD, place it in your laptop and reboot it. Maybe you will need to have some fun in the `BIOS` (like setting up the boot order), but other than that, this should be all you should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should go [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) to download Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 32-bit or 64-bit. (I recommend 64-bit)

While running Windows XP, if you don't have any program to burn the image to a CD, i recommend [cdburnerxp](http://cdburnerxp.se/), which is a free and very good program to burn CD/DVD.

Then you just have to put the CD into your laptop, and select the option to boot from CD, either from BIOS or pressing a shortcut while booting, F10 or F12, depends on the laptop manufactor.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you I would rather make a bootable USB stick if i were you. The installation is faster and you save a CD-rom. These are the steps:

1. Download ubuntu 12.04 from [Ubuntu download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), and save it somewhere you can find.
   If you are not sure whether to use 32 or 64 bit chose 32 bit.
2. Download universal USB installer from  [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button), and install
3. Create the bootable USB by following the rest of [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).
4. Make sure the Ubuntu bootable usb-stick is still attached to the laptop and then restart your computer and go to the BIOS - go to boot settings and make sure that usb devices will be 1st priority in boot list.
5. Save and Exit and the USB will be booted and the installation will start. Follow instructions.
6. Enjoy Unity.
7. You can download the manual "Getting started with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from [here](http://ubuntu-manual.org/downloads)